# Regex problem in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to create a regex that will matches with

```
"8-9."
```

but won't matches with

```
"8-9........"
```

I tried lots of possibilities yet, but still can't find the right one.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and how it fails.

Comment: To be clear: you want to match exactly the characters "8-9." (eight dash nine dot) and that's not a regex pattern, yes?  Or do you want to match all digits between 8 and 9 followed by any character?

Comment: What is the string you want to match? What do you not want to match? how does the pattern look that you have tried? ... You need to be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Dim r As Regex = New Regex("8\-9")
'Look for match
Dim m As Match = r.Match(mystring)
```

also might use

```
Dim r As Regex = New Regex("^8\-9$")
```

if you want a single word

Comment: `-` has no special meaning unless it's used inside a character class (e.g. `[a-z]`).

Comment: In VB, `x As Y = new Y…` should *always* be replaced by `x As New Y…`.

Comment: @Konrad, is that VB's equivalent of `var`? I've always wondered.

Comment: @Blindy No. VB’s equivalent of `var` is `Dim` without a data type, when `Option Infer` is enabled. So just `Dim x = "Hello"`. However, due to the above-mentioned syntax shortcut, this is less often necessary than `var` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Without a better worded question, `^8-9$` should do it..